# How can I send an SMS message from my Mac?

Tags: macos, messages, sms

I want to know how I can send a SMS message (not an iMessage) from my Mac. I don't have great Wi-Fi right now, so I need to send a text message in order for it to go through. I know to send one on an iPhone, one needs to hold down the message bubble, but I don't know how to send one on OS X.

Comment: You can't send a text message on Wi-Fi, unless you set up Text Message Forwarding between your iPhone and Mac.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [Text Message Forwarding](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22363) and requires iOS 8.1 or above. Make sure both the OS X Messages App and your iPhone have the same Apple ID enabled. Then, do the following:

1. On your iPhone, tap Settings > Messages.
2. Tap Text Message Forwarding.
3. Enable your Mac in the list of devices.
4. On your Mac, open Messages.
5. A six-digit activation code appears.
6. Enter this code on your iPhone, then tap Allow.

That should just about do it.

Comment: Nope, that's not it.  There is no "Text Message Forwarding" under Message in settings.  Thanks for playing.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me as I am not sure where in the world you are, but at least here in the US you can typically send text messages in one of two ways (other than by phone):

1. Using the recipient's carrier's email-to-SMS gateway (typically something like NNNNNNNNNN@txt.carrier.com).
2. Using the recipient's carrier's send-a-text website.

This assumes, of course, that you know which carrier your recipient is using. If you do, doing a web search for one of the above along with the carrier name is likely to provide you with a solution.